# Problems with Solr in CKAN

Tags: solr, ckan

I have a problem with solr and ckan.

I understood that Solr is not directly linked to PostgreSQL. The Solr index is maintained by the CKAN code itself.

I've lost all Solr's information because its broken so now I cant do queries in Solr. How can recover all the data in Solr?

Any crawling method that can help me? Or is it enough to dump my ckan database and export/import again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `search-index` command](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/paster.html#search-index-rebuild-search-index) for CKAN's CLI to rebuild to Solr index:

> Rebuilds the search index. This is useful to prevent search indexes from getting out of sync with the main database.
>
> For example:
>
> `paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild --config=/etc/ckan/std/std.ini`
>
> This default behaviour will clear the index and rebuild it with all datasets. If you want to rebuild it for only one dataset, you can provide a dataset name:
>
> `paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild test-dataset-name --config=/etc/ckan/std/std.ini`

Comment: Hi! I dont have the std.ini file. Any guide o cammands to creare it? Thanks for answer me!

Comment: That would be your regular configuration file, or if you don't have one, you can probably just leave it out to have paster use the default config.

Comment: Oh! I've understood you now! It is the configuration file that you created in step 4 on this tutorial! http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#create-a-ckan-config-file

Comment: Correct - paster has to know how your CKAN instance is configured to know how to query the correct instance.